# How to dynamically append textbox in a form using a function associated to button click

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, append

Here is what I attempt to do

[image]

When I hit the button the textbox is not appended correctly but I've this output instead:

[image]

Also if I write text in the textbox and then press the button, the text inside textbox (in this case, the email) will be also duplicated, is there any way to avoid this?

```js
var newtb, reftb

function addElement() {
  newtb = document.getElementById("mail") //***
  reftb = document.getElementById("phone")
  document.getElementById("myForm").insertBefore(newtb, reftb)
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your first name"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Enter your last name"><br><br>
  <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter your email">
  <input type="button" id="addElementButton" value="+" onclick="addElement()"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number"><br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use document.createElement

```js
var cnt=0;
function addElement() {
  var reftb = document.getElementById("phone")
  var mail = document.createElement("input");
  mail.type="text";
  mail.id="mail"+(++cnt);
  mail.placeholder="Enter your email"
  document.getElementById("myForm").insertBefore(mail, reftb)
  document.getElementById("myForm").insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), reftb);
document.getElementById("myForm").insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), reftb);

}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your first name"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Enter your last name"><br><br>
  <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter your email">
  <input type="button" id="addElementButton" value="+" onclick="addElement()"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number"><br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
</form>
```

Comment: Understood, this was easier than I expected, thank you for your answer, it works fine now!

Comment: If I want to do the same thing with "phone" the fuction can't work because under the textbox "phone" there's nothing. Which value should "reftb" have in this case? Thanks.

Comment: How about "submit" ?

Comment: Oh right, I thought it couldn't work because it wasn't a textbox, I've read the specification of the function 5 minutes later posting the question and realized how dumb it was :P 

Thanks :>